# Login test with swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, authentication

I am doing a login test, my api is http://163.18.22.78/api/Login, when the login is successful return ["result": "success"] on the contrary login is returned ["result": "Success"], and now the problem is that I received a response from the server, the response is above ["result": "success"] and ["result": "failed"], I want him to jump when successful To the next page, fail to jump out of the warning box, but I do not understand this and not to write this part of the code (json parse), please help solve this doubt, thank you

Here are my login code:

```
 func login_now(username:String,password:String) {


    let parameters = ["account": nametextField.text!, "password": passwordTextField.text!] as Dictionary<String, String>

    //create the url with URL
    let url = URL(string: "http://163.18.22.78/api/Login")! 

    //create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData


    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

            return
        }

        let json: Any?

        do
        {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        }
        catch
        {
            return
        }

        guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
        {
            return
        }


        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                print(json)
                if let data_block = server_response["result"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let session_data = data_block["success"] as? String {
                        self.login_session = session_data
                        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                        preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.LoginDone()
                        }
                    }
                }


            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()

}
```

and here is my server of login code
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 let val = data_block["result"]!
  if val as? String  == "Success"{
          // push to next view
    }
    else{
        // show alert
    }
```

Comment: if let data_block = server_response["result"] as? NSDictionary {
 if let session_data = data_block["result"] as? String == "success"{

Comment: like this?But it's say Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not bool

Comment: Key inside what should fill in, because this syntax has been wrong